# Javascript - Update array with passed parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters

I have a bunch of input elements which calls a function when clicked. They pass along a bunch of parameters with information about what was clicked.

Like so:

```
onClick="updateCart('product_id', 'product_name', 'product_price');"
```

Now I want to create a function which take these parameters and put them in an array.

```
var updateCart = function (product_type, product_id, cost_model_id, product_name, subscription_campaign, startup_campaign) {
    this.product_row = [];
};
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Read about [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, the easiest way will be to use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) variable, which will contain all passed parameters in array-like format. You should transform it to array as follows:

```
var updateCart = function() {
    this.product_row = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // another way: this.product_row = [].slice.call(arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var updateCart = function (product_type, product_id, cost_model_id, product_name, subscription_campaign, startup_campaign) {
    this.product_row = [ product_type, product_id, cost_model_id, product_name, subscription_campaign, startup_campaign ];
};
```

Isn't that what you're looking for?

When retrieving the information you just use:

```
this.product_row[0]; //returns product_type
```

But if you need something more readable, use an object instead:

```
var updateCart = function (product_type, product_id, cost_model_id, product_name, subscription_campaign, startup_campaign) {
    this.product_row = { "productType": product_type, "productID": product_id, "costModelID": cost_model_id, "productName": product_name, "subscriptionCampaign": subscription_campaign, "startupCampaign": startup_campaign };
};
```